# Apache : set different users depending on the folder

Tags: php, apache

I've searched for a moment, but I didn't anything that helps me.

I'm working in a LAMP environment. The document root of my website is on /var/www, and I have configured Apache to run with user "vendor".

Now, I have created a subfolder /var/www/plugins, and I would like any http request on a page of this subfolder to be executed as "client". The goal is to purpose a plugin system to my clients, but I don't want them to see the code of the project core. So, if his code is executed with another user, I can set the privileges on the files to choose what file I let him include and read.

I have tried to use UserDir directive, but when I call the php function get_current_user(), 
I still have "vendor".

Please help me ;(

Comment: If you look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_userdir.html it's just about setting up users on the system with their own directories, not about switching the user running apache.

Comment: But. Perhaps this could help you: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/suexec.html

Comment: Thank's very much. It seems to be exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use suPHP, an apache module. Install it, enable it with the command

```
a2enmod suphp
```

Then, to configure it, you have to do the following actions :

1.In apache2.conf, add the following line at the end of the file :

`LoadModule suphp_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_suphp.so`

2.In the file /etc/apache2/mods-available/suphp.conf

```
<IfModule mod_suphp.so>
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php

    suPHP_AddHandler x-httpd-php
    suPHP_AddHandler x-httpd-php5

    suPHP_Engine on

#Use a specific php config file (a dir which contains a php.ini file)
#   suPHP_ConfigPath /etc/php5/cgi/suphp/
# # Tells mod_suphp NOT to handle requests with the type <mime-type>.
#   suPHP_RemoveHandler <mime-type>
</IfModule>
```

3.In the file /etc/suphp/suphp.conf

```
[handlers]
;Handler for php-scripts
application/x-httpd-php5="php:/usr/bin/php5-cgi"
application/x-httpd-php="php:/usr/bin/php5-cgi"
```

4.In your virtual host file, for the directory you want to execute with a different user :

```
<Directory "/your/folder">
        php_admin_flag engine off
        suPHP_Engine on
        suPHP_AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5
        suPHP_AddHandler application/x-httpd-php        
</Directory>
```

Doing that, when you'll execute a php file in this folder, the executer will be the owner of the file.

Thank's a lot to EJEHardenberg, your comment permitted me to find the answer to this issue.